# eclipse, StatET, sending R remotely debugging

Tags: eclipse, r, statet

I have a database on a remote server as well as R located on an altogether different server.  I access the database from my R script.  I am using Eclipse with StatET on my local machine.  Is there a way to use the debugging features of eclipse and make the script execute remotely on the server containing R?  I keep running into things like remote console and various other scripts but can't seem to figure out what I actually need to do.  My local machine is Windows, servers are both unix.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't tried very hard to get StatET debugging working, but AFAIK this is only available for debugging packages that have been compiled in a specific way.  For debugging your scripts, you may have more luck trying the R debugging tools.  See `?debug` or  `?browser`.

Comment: yes, this is what i'm currently using. thanks for the help though.